# Can i use a for loop to concat dataframe with variable?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to concat the dataframe based on input number by for loop

My code:

```py
combine_df = pd.DataFrame()
df1= pd.DataFrame()
df2= pd.DataFrame()
df3= pd.DataFrame()
df4= pd.DataFrame()
df5= pd.DataFrame()

number = 5
for i in range(1,number):
    master_df = pd.concat([master_df, "df"+str(i)],ignore_index=True,sort=False)
```

The following is the error

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'str'>"; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid
```

The reason I want to do this is I want to create n number of dataframe and concat n number of dataframe based on input number n

eg. if the number = 10, i can get 10 dataframe combined

Comment: how about using list `list_df = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5]`

Comment: What do you mean by _based on input number by for loop_? What are you trying to do here, what is your expected result?

Comment: The reason I want to do this is I want to create n number of dataframe and concat n number of dataframe based on input number n

eg. if the number = 10, i can get 10 dataframe combined

Comment: doing `'df'+str(i)` creates a string and not a variable and you cannot concat strings with the pd.concat method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can concat like this, but i'm not sure you'll get the expected output. You have to use eval as well. Here is an example of some sample data i have doing this:

```
d                                                                                                                                                                                                
#{'foo': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'bar': ['d', 'e', 'f']}

e                                                                                                                                                                                                
#{'car': ['ford', 'honda', 'acura'], 'what': ['huh', 'yeah', 'ok']}

combine_df = pd.DataFrame()
df1= pd.DataFrame()
df2= pd.DataFrame(d)
df3= pd.DataFrame()
df4= pd.DataFrame(e)
df5= pd.DataFrame()

number = 5
for i in range(1,number):
    master_df = pd.concat([master_df, eval("df"+str(i))],ignore_index=True,sort=False)

master_df
#Out[2284]: 
#   foo  bar    car  what
#0    a    d    NaN   NaN
#1    b    e    NaN   NaN
#2    c    f    NaN   NaN
#3  NaN  NaN   ford   huh
#4  NaN  NaN  honda  yeah
#5  NaN  NaN  acura    ok
```

Comment: nice. This is what exact I am looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Kevin, if this is the right answer, would you be so kind to click the checkmark under the arrows up and down? Thanks, i upvoted you for +10

Comment: Done! Thanks for helping.